# Cannot programmatically get public IP Address of the VirtualMachineScaleSet instances

Tags: java, azure, sdk, azure-sdk-for-java

I programmatically (Azure, Java SDK) create Virtual Machine Scale Set ((Linux OS - Ubuntu) with ".withVirtualMachinePublicIp()" option during the creation. It works OK, I can see the instances and their public IP Addresses in the Azure Portal. I can ssh into the instances, etc...  However I cannot get the public IP Addresses via Azure Java API, it always returns **null**.  I tried a lot , the below code is just one of the attempts.

```
 //vmss is a good working recently created instance off
 //com.azure.resourcemanager.compute.models.VirtualMachineScaleSet class

 for (VirtualMachineScaleSetNetworkInterface nis : vmss.listNetworkInterfaces()) 
 {
  String privip=nis.primaryPrivateIP();//works OK
  Map<String, VirtualMachineScaleSetNicIpConfiguration> mp=nis.ipConfigurations();
  for (Object key: mp.keySet()) 
  {
   VirtualMachineScaleSetNicIpConfiguration vip=mp.get(key);
   String priva=vip.privateIpAddress();//works OK
   String pipa=vip.innerModel().publicIpAddress().ipAddress();//always returns null
   String pss=vip.innerModel().privateIpAddress();
   System.out.println("PublicIP="+pipa+",PrivateIP="+priva+"="+pss);//Public IP is always null
  }
 }
```

I tried the above code but always receive null value as Public IP Address

Answer (score 0):

I was helped on Git Hub. There is workaround:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/33299#issuecomment-1415416429

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).